# How does Infrastructure impact on Aggregate Supply?

Tags: macroeconomics

I was just wondering how Infrastructure can impact on Aggregate Supply. More specifically, how does the improvement of infrastructure improve Aggregate Supply?

Comment: If you found the answer helpful please upvote/accept answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Aggregate supply is typically modelled as

$$ Y = F(A, K, L) $$

where

$Y$ = total production

$L$ = labour input

$K$ = capital input

$A$ = total factor productivity

Investment in infrastructure can increase both capital input $K$ and total factor productivity $A$. In a standard $AS - AD$ model, the aggregate supply curve would shift to the right, as a result, and the equilibrium output of the economy would increase.

[image]

Investment in infrastructure can increase **capital input**, because if there are more roads in the country, the economy can produce more goods and services (think about a truck company, for example, which can do more jobs per day if its trucks travel on more direct roads or faster highways).

It can also increase **total factor productivity**, because the proportional increase in output is potentially higher than the proportional increase in capital input. If with a short road I link a town to a national highway network, the benefits can be disproportionally high, as a short road link now provides access to a huge existing highway network. Or think about the 50 mile Panama Canal. It provides ships an 8,000 mile shortcut.